# How to use spark-job server for Java Project?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark in java project.
I tried to use spark-jobserver as our webservice. But faced a lot difficults.
Is there any sample java project to use spark-job server?

My question:
It seems  only need to implements the SparkJob in our java class and override the method runJob.
But I find that in the runJob method, the sparkcontext type is SparkContext, not JavaSparkContext which we used in our java project.

```
public Object runJob(SparkContext sparkcontext, Config config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

So I changed JavaSparkContext to SparkContext in our job class. But I faced another compile issue.
Please help to correct me. Thanks

before change:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Row> pairData;

.................
JavaSchemaRDD schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(pairData.values(), schema);
```

after change

```
// because we I need to use SparkContext, so I changed JavaPairRDD<String, Row> to  RDD<Tuple2<String, Row>>.

RDD<Tuple2<String, Row>> pairData;
...............................


// I can't use pairData.values(), So I transform pairData to rowRDD


RDD<Row> rowRDD = pairData .map(new Function<Tuple2<String, Row>, Row>() {
 public Row call(Tuple2<String, Row> re)
 throws Exception {
 return re._2();
 }

  });
```

But I found there is a compile error on the .map method. Moreover **I found we can't use any class under package  org.apache.spark.sql.api.java if I changed JavaSparkContext to SparkContext in our job class.
Is there a java job class example?**

Comment: Its confusing but spark-java is a different project unrelated to apache-spark or spark-jobserver.

Comment: @simafengyun : Hi, How did you made it run finally? I also need exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaSparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) has methods to convert to a `SparkContext` and vice versa, look at the methods `JavaSparkContext.sc()` and `JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this here for an example of how to do that. -> [Spark Job Server with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904861/spark-job-server-with-java)